# How can I collect Productivity Metrics by Author on Mercurial using Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, metrics

I'm using Sonar Qube Version 5.1.1 and I was studying about how to collect productivity metrics by author. The most of sonar metrics is related to the structure project. I found the [scm-stats](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-scm-stats). However, the actual version seems to have some problems with Mercurial repositories. So, anyone has some suggestion about a plugin/tool or strategy to calculate some metrics by author related to commit on Sonar.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Developer Cockpit](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/developer-tools/developer-cockpit/) plugin.

Comment: Hi G. Ann. Thanks for your response. I saw Developer Cockpit and sounds like a great tool, but it has a high price (7k). So, I was looking for other possibilities to compare the benefits. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry @ManueleFerreira, that's all I'm aware of.